# How can I print the name of files along with unique entries in each file?

Tags: file, unix, unique

I have around 100 files in a folder and I want to count the no of unique elements in in coloumn 1. I tried the following code and it gives me the only the number of each files. What I need is the unique number and also the file name for each case.

```
for f in *.bxout; do awk '{print $1}' "$f" | sort| uniq | wc -l ; done
```

the output is like

```
68

45

…..

141
```

what I need

```
68 fille1.txt

45 fille13.txt

….

141 fille15.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concat the filename after your pipeline like this:

```
for f in *.bxout; do echo "$(awk '{print $1}' "$f" | sort| uniq | wc -l) $f" ; done
```

Reducing the pipeline to single `awk` command:

```
$ cat a.bxout 
1
1
2
$ cat b.bxout 
1
1
2
3
$ for f in *.bxout; do awk '{arr[$1]} END{for(key in arr) cnt++; print cnt " " FILENAME}' "$f"; done
2 a.bxout
3 b.bxout
```

Comment: how can I reduce it to single awk?

Comment: @ ritesht93 yes it prints the file name   now output is like that                  <68 dataset1.bxout
67 dataset2bxout
67 dataset3.bxout
269 dataset4.bxout>

Answer (score 0):

Another way without awk, just simple `cat` and `uniq`

```
for f in `ls *.bxout`;do cnt=`cat $f|uniq|wc -l`;echo "$cnt $f";done
```